# Symantec Gateway Security 320 VPN/Port Forwarding trouble

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, vpn, symantec, tunneling

How do I check to see if port forward is enabled with one of my dynamic tunnels on this device? I'm having trouble using a feature in our software that requires a vpn to be used. My firewalls shows it as connected but I'm unable to ping the subnet ip. Our software vendor told me that port forwarding might be causing this problem, but I didn't set up this network I'm on and I don't fully know symantec hardware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have access to the SGS 320 interface?  Can you view logs?

Not sure if you have the admin guide. This is a symantec FTP site and is a PDF of the manual. [SGS 300 Admin Manual](ftp://ftp.symantec.com/public/english_us_canada/products/symantec_gateway_security/300-Series_2.0/manuals/SGS300_ADM.pdf)